# How do I request a refund for the purchase of additional weight in XCM ？(not just for instructions that were never dispatched)

Tags: xcm, weight

XCM version: 3

#### 1. I bought 3_000_000 weight, but it might actually only need 3000 weight, how can I refund the fees of (3_000_000-3000) weight?

```rust
ParaA::execute_with(|| {
    let message = Xcm(vec![
        WithdrawAsset(
            (Here, send_amount).into(),
        ),
        BuyExecution { fees: (Here, send_amount).into(), weight_limit: Limited(3_000_000) },
        DepositAsset { assets: All.into(), beneficiary: Parachain(2).into() },
    ]);
    // Send withdraw and deposit
    assert_ok!(ParachainPalletXcm::send_xcm(Here, Parent, message.clone()));
});
```

#### 2. I can use `RefundSurplus` in `ErrorHandler`, but it seems that the refund surplus only related to the count of instructions after the `Trap`, even though I bought far more weight than needed. For example `RefundSurplus` of code(1) get more refund than code(2) only because of it has more instructions than code(2) after `Trap`, right?

code 1:

```rust
ParaA::execute_with(|| {
    let message = Xcm(vec![
        WithdrawAsset(
            (Here, send_amount).into(),
        ),
        BuyExecution { fees: (Here, send_amount).into(), weight_limit: Limited(3_000_000) },
        SetErrorHandler(Xcm(vec![
            RefundSurplus,
            DepositAsset { assets: All.into(), beneficiary: Parachain(2).into() },
        ])),
        Trap(0),
        DepositAsset { assets: All.into(), beneficiary: Parachain(2).into() },
        DepositAsset { assets: All.into(), beneficiary: Parachain(2).into() },
        DepositAsset { assets: All.into(), beneficiary: Parachain(2).into() },
    ]);
    // Send withdraw and deposit
    assert_ok!(ParachainPalletXcm::send_xcm(Here, Parent, message.clone()));
});
```

code 2:

```rust
ParaA::execute_with(|| {
    let message = Xcm(vec![
        WithdrawAsset(
            (Here, send_amount).into(),
        ),
        BuyExecution { fees: (Here, send_amount).into(), weight_limit: Limited(3_000_000) },
        SetErrorHandler(Xcm(vec![
            RefundSurplus,
            DepositAsset { assets: All.into(), beneficiary: Parachain(2).into() },
        ])),
        Trap(0),
        DepositAsset { assets: All.into(), beneficiary: Parachain(2).into() },
    ]);
    // Send withdraw and deposit
    assert_ok!(ParachainPalletXcm::send_xcm(Here, Parent, message.clone()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The official answer is that you need to reclaim your trapped assets as shown by this test:

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/e85f2d3355e909a82d936b259548385835c4398b/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/tests.rs#L532

However I think it ought to be possible to set an appendix in the original xcm so that the surplus is redirected back to the source:

```rust
SetAppendix(Xcm(vec![                   
    RefundSurplus,
    DepositAsset { assets: All.into(), max_assets: 1, beneficiary: source.clone() },
])),
```

Imperially it does not seem that you need to buy additional execution (`buy_execution((Here, SEND_AMOUNT)),`) in the appendix (which is good as I was worried about a chicken and egg situation).